# Вывод/ввод информации без использования стандартных библиотек

Tags: c++

Как в С++ можно выводить информацию на экран(либо в файл) без использования каких-либо подключаемых библиотек, т.е. без iostream, stdio и т.д. Как вообще работают функции printf(), scanf() и объекты cout, cin и как их можно реализовать самому?

Comment: https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.24/vfprintf_8c_source.html наслаждайтесь )

Comment: А зачем всётаки?

Comment: У windows есть таблица KeServices, через Int2E если я не ошибаюсь,  можно получить доступ к основым функциям. У линукса само удобно через syscall который тоже доступен через int.

Comment: Если интересна ревлизация, можете посмотреть [musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree), еще один вариант libc (основная библиотека, связывающая C/C++ с ядром ОС) для Linux (хотя большинство функций системонезависимы).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ввод-вывод предусмотрен в языке лишь в форме функциональности стандартной библиотеки. Если вы не используете её, вам придётся обходиться дополнительными платформозависимыми средствами, которые предоставляет вам операционная система. Например, для Windows это WinAPI, то есть функции наподобие [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), доступные только под этой платформой.

При этом ваша программа, понятно, теряет кроссплатформенность.

---

Поскольку имплементация библиотечных функций построена под капотом на системно-зависимом API, понятно, что таким образом можно построить свой аналогичный велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Через вызовы операционной системы.

Работаете под DOS :) - используйте прерывания DOS/BIOS или прямой вывод в видеопамять, под Windows - например, `WriteFile` в стандартный вывод, или семейство `Console`... Под Linux - ее API.